# How to build this Gantt Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, charts

i want to build an easy Gantt Chart but the tikz document is way to hard for me. Can someone help me with that Ganttchart i have in my picture?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[colorlinks= false, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I have no clue to start. Can someone please help me a bit? I am a total newbie on latex....

[image: withouttheyellowcolor!]

Comment: @cfr thanks for editing! oh man im suche a newbie...

Comment: I suggest starting by looking at the package's documentation. That is the way to become less of a newbie. Simply copy-pasting code from others will not help you get to grips with things. Getting help when you get stuck, on the other hand, would be really helpful.

Comment: @Milo Li The figure does not looks to me as a gantt chart. Instead, it looks as a time schedule for machines or processes. I vaguely remember as a graph of operations research.

Comment: @MiloLi, adding to cfr's comment: if the Ti*k*Z documentation is to extensive for you, perhaps look at the [`pgfgantt`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf)'s documentation. To draw the Gantt Chart it's not required to know Ti*k*Z... `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `pgfgantt` what you have to read is `pgfgantt` documentation which is not so intimidating like `TiKZ`'s one. Although it's convenient to have some `TiKZ` notions which can be obtained taking a look at first tutorials in `TiKZ` documentation.

All packages documentation is on your system and, probably, you can open it with command `texdoc name-of-package`.

Following examples in `pgfgantt` documentation it's easy to obtain

[image]

which is not exactly what you want, but similar. I'm sure that after some look at `pgfgantt` documentation you will easily understand the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[%
inline, 
bar inline label anchor=west,
bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=white},
bar/.append style={fill=cyan!90!black,}, 
bar height=.8,]{0}{18}
\gantttitlelist{0,...,18}{1}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J2}{3}{4}
\ganttbar{}{5}{18}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M2}{0}{5}
\ganttbar{J2}{5}{8}
\ganttbar{J1}{8}{12}
\ganttbar{}{12}{18}
\end{ganttchart}
\caption{To demonstrate Flow shop Scheduling}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```